# If I set an Android 4.0 to use face recognition, after which I shave my head, will face recognition still work?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, face-unlock

I was reading about the new face recognition unlock of Android 4.0 and was just wondering that , if I should shave my head afterwards, the face recognition still would work ?

Comment: I would guess yes. Your hair is not part of your face (excepting the obvious facial hair like beards and so forth).

Answer (score 4):

You can "recalibrate" face unlock by switching to another type of lock screen and back, as this causes a new reference image to be taken. Meanwhile you can unlock the device with secondary measures (either PIN or pattern unlock).

Comment: Yes, of course, obviously you can always take another reference photo. I know that. That was, of course, not the intended answer. (not that it matters so much, of course, I was just wandering about this).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work, Since the Face recognition technology in Android ICS is designed to match the face with the help of **points of recognition** as shown bellow.

[image: Face Recognition]

Majority points will be applied on the facial parts. So it should recognize your face.